# pthread_create allocates a lot of memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

Here's a simple example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

void* run(void*)
{
    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<pthread_t> workers(192);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        pthread_create(&workers[i], nullptr, &run, nullptr);

    pthread_join(workers.back(), nullptr);
}
```

`top` shows `1'889'356 KiB` `VIRT`! I know this isn't resident memory, but still, this is huge amount of memory for a single thread creation.

Is it really so memory-expensive (8MiB in this case) to create a thread? Is this configurable?

Or, maybe and most probably, I have some misunderstanding what virtual memory is?

---

Details:

I double quadruple-checked the memory usage, using:

- generated a `core dump` of the running exe, it's also 1.6GB;
- `valgrind --tool=massif` also confirms this size;
- `pmap -x <pid>` also confirms the size.

As this size matches the max size of a stack (also confirmed by `/proc/<pid>/limits`), I tried to make the max size of the stack smaller. Tried with 1 MiB, but this didn't change anything.

Please, put aside the creation and usage of 192 threads, it has a reason behind it.

Sorry for the mixed C and C++ - initially tried with `std::thread` and the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pthread_attr_setstacksize()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html) function is available to set stack size.
This function have to be used with an thread attribute object.
The thread attribute object has to be passed as 2nd argument of `pthread_create()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

void* run(void*)
{
    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<pthread_t> workers(192);
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 16384);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        pthread_create(&workers[i], &attr, &run, nullptr);

    pthread_join(workers.back(), nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Oh, damn, that really works! So, it really does take so much memory and it really is because of the stack size. Thanks, appreciated!